# How to navigate full screen from BottomModalSheet

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

The problem is this, I have a ModalBottomSheet dialog that is expanded on a WelcomeScreen, inside the ModalBottomSheet ViewModel I do the logic to log in the user, once the user is logged in the idea is it navigates into MyProfile Screen, it works but only navigates the part of the ModalBottomSheet.

Someone have some idea to do that?

Thanks in advance!

BottomSheetSignIn.kt

```
@Composable
fun CardContent(
  signInViewModel: SignInViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
  navigateToSignUp: () -> Unit,
  navigateToMyProfileScreen: () -> Unit,
  navigateToWelcomeScreen: () -> Unit
) {
  val signInState = signInViewModel.signInState.collectAsState(initial = null).value
  println("signInState: $signInState")
  val emailValue = signInViewModel.email.collectAsState().value
  val passwordValue = signInViewModel.password.collectAsState().value
  val validForm = signInViewModel.formError.collectAsState().value
  val context = LocalContext.current

  when {
    signInState?.isLoading == true -> {
      Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp)
      ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
      }
    }

    signInState?.isSuccess?.isNotEmpty() == true -> {
      navigateToMyProfileScreen()
      signInViewModel.clearResource()
    }

    signInState?.isError?.isNotEmpty() == true -> {
      Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        val error = signInState.isError
        Toast.makeText(context, "$error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
      signInViewModel.clearResource()
    }
  }


  Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 36.dp)
  ) {
    CustomSpacer(size = 8.dp)
    CardHandler()
    CustomSpacer(size = 16.dp)
    CardTitle(string.welcome_back)
    CardSubtitle(string.enter_details_below)
    CustomSpacer(size = 16.dp)
    EmailTextField(
      emailValue = emailValue,
      onValueChange = { signInViewModel.onValuesSignInChange(it, passwordValue) }
    )
    CustomSpacer(size = 16.dp)
    PasswordTextField(
      passwordValue = passwordValue,
      onValueChange = { signInViewModel.onValuesSignInChange(emailValue, it) }
    )
    CustomSpacer(size = 24.dp)
    SmallButtonDark(
      onClick = { signInViewModel.signInWithEmailAndPasswordIntent() },
      text = string.sign_in,
      enabled = validForm
    )
    CustomSpacer(size = 16.dp)
    ForgotPasswordText()
    CustomSpacer(size = 40.dp)
    OtherLoginMethodsSection(string.not_registered_yet_signup_with)
    CustomSpacer(size = 24.dp)
    OtherLoginIconButtons(
      firstMethod = { Toast.makeText(context, "Do Google Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() },
      secondMethod = navigateToSignUp
    )
  }
}
```

Result: [it only shows on dialog part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/codl3.png)

Comment: The navigation logic is outside the code that you posted. It is higher up in the call hierarchy where the `CardContent` is composed. Posting snippets of code related to those parts would help.